# Selecting multiple selectors with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of items already stored in variables as jQuery selectors, like this:

```
var $description = $("#description");
var $title = $("#title");
var $fname = $("#fname");
var $sname = $("#sname");
// ...
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$($description, $title, $fname, $sname).change(function(){ /*...*/ });
```

Is that possible?

Comment: @Liam & @Satpal - I don't really see it as the same question as the one indicated, as that's really asking for the `$("xxx, yyy")` solution, whereas my question is specifically about already already having the JQuery elements in variables. (Even th.ough the answer to that question contains the answer to this one)

Comment: If you want I will reopen it, However solution is clearly there `$('.class1').add('.class2')`, I am sure @Rory would have reopened it otherwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `add()` to join jQuery objects already in variables together:

```
$description.add($title).add($fname).add($sname).change(function() {
    // do something...
});
```

Comment: wow, that was quick! thanks. I couldn't turn up the result I wanted by Googling as I was just getting normal Jquery "selection/selector" results back.